# How to save curl_exec result into variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm new to Laravel. Trying to work with external API.

In **controller** i wont just to make variable with json:

```
 $testapi = new TestApi();
 $data['books'] = $testapi->books();
 return view('books.index', $data);
```

In **model** (just php class without any extends) this:

```
public function books()
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->host."/books");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

But json content is placed at the beggining of HTML file, even before META information. curl_exec don't save result to variable, but transfer it to global result. How to save this json to variable and then use inside template?

Comment: Make your life easier: learn Guzzle.

Comment: The problem was just because of `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);`

Comment: Yes. Guzzle provides a much nicer API in front of cURL, and is widely used throughout Laravel. You should consider learning it, as it'll make your cURLing a lot easier/cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
```

that will allow the return to be put into your $result variable, instead of outputting directly.